# Can I use Visual composer plugin in a custom front-end which is detached from WordPress Admin

Tags: wordpress

Basically our architecture is such that we are using a headless WordPrss CMS. Meaning out data is managed through WordPress admin. However the front end is to be built using any front end frameworks like Angular etc. So my question is, if I have a license of Visual composer and installed it in WordPress through admin. Can I use Visual composer in front end which is custom and not a normal WordPress theme?

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible, but it's not something that will work out of the box. Your custom frontend will have to 'understand' the content Visual Composer produces, thus VC has to be loaded in the frontend as well.

On a data level VC populates the post with custom shortcodes and 'deciphers' them in the frontend. Start with VC Wiki: https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Visual+Composer+Pagebuilder+for+WordPress and specifically API section: https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Inner+API